# In Python how can I copy a list of dictionaries, and filter specific keys, including nested ones?

Tags: python

If I have a dictionary, which contains lists, dictionaries, strings, and integers, how can I copy that dictionary, but only specific white listed keys?

Filtering `old_dict` through this function would give me `new_dict`. The white listed keys can be in whatever format, but the solution should be able to take an object of arbitrary white listed keys to produce the output.

```
old_dict = [
    {
        'name': {'first': "John", 'last': "Doe"},
        'groups': ["foo", "bar"],
        'widgets': [
            {'id': 0, 'name': "Acme"},
            {'id': 1, 'name': "Anvil"},
        ],
    },

    {
        'name': {'first': "David"},
        'groups': ["bar", "bash", "ding"],
        'widgets': [
            {'id': 1, 'name': "Anvil"},
            {'id': 8, 'name': "Bingo"},
        ],
    },
]

new_dict = [
    {
        'name': {'last': "Doe"},
        'widgets': [
            {'name': "Acme"},
            {'name': "Anvil"},
        ],
    },

    {
        'name': { },
        'widgets': [
            {'name': "Anvil"},
            {'name': "Bingo"},
        ],
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_dict = []
for dic in old_dic:
    new_dict.append({})
    for key in white_list: #list of keys
        if key in dic:
            new_dict[key] = old_dic[key]
```

Which you can make in to a list comprehension as:

```
new_dic = [ dict( key, old_dic[key])
                 for key in whitelist
                 if key in old_dic)
            for dic in old_dic ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a recursive function that handles each type and filters out whenever you see a dict:

```
def keep_only(keys, val):
    if type(val) is list:
        return [keep_only(keys, v) for v in val]
    if type(val) is dict:
        return dict((k, keep_only(keys, v)) for k,v in val.items() if k in keys)
    return val
```

Sample usage:

```
>>> old_dict = [
    {
        'name': {'first': "John", 'last': "Doe"},
        'groups': ["foo", "bar"],
        'widgets': [
            {'id': 0, 'name': "Acme"},
            {'id': 1, 'name': "Anvil"},
        ],
    },

    {
        'name': {'first': "David"},
        'groups': ["bar", "bash", "ding"],
        'widgets': [
            {'id': 1, 'name': "Anvil"},
            {'id': 8, 'name': "Bingo"},
        ],
    },
]
>>> keep_only(set(['name', 'widgets', 'last']), old_dict)
[{'widgets': [{'name': 'Acme'}, {'name': 'Anvil'}], 'name': {'last': 'Doe'}}, {'widgets': [{'name': 'Anvil'}, {'name': 'Bingo'}], 'name': {}}]
```